# Charging laptop using PD emulator

Tags: laptop, battery

[Image of PD emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBFud.jpg)

My laptop doesn't charge via USB-c so I bought a PD emulator that plugs into the barrel port and charges the laptop through a USB c cable. **But I can only charge my laptop by this method when the laptop is off or in sleep mode. Why doesn't it charge my laptop when it's on(in working mode).**
I am using a 65W PD charger. I think some drivers or services are interfering with the charging process. Anyway, I could not fix the problem. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Get a proper charger for your laptop.

A proper PD charger will be able to output one or more voltages from a selection of 5V, 9V, 12V, 15V or 20V. Depending on the device being charged there may be a slight difference in what voltage is suppled. A "true" PD device will toggle or signal on one of the USB C connector lines to negotiate a voltage. A "dumb" PD device may put a particular load across the (different) data lines to "signal" that it wants 9V instead of 5V.

Not knowing what that PD "emulator" is limits what we can say about it. It is entirely possible that is only knows how to "ask" for 9V from your charger and so limits charge rate that way. Or it knows how to ask for 12V but not a higher current and so you only get a slow charge. Cheap devices like these tend to be very limited in what they do and there may be lots of different adaptors for various different voltage and current requirements.  You may have gotten (or been sent) the wrong one for your particular requirements.

I doubt it is a problem with "drivers or services" on your computer. The problem is that unknown chunk of questionable hardware between your laptop and the charger.

Comment: The PD charger that I bought outputs all of those voltages that you have mentioned(at least they claim to). The PD emulator outputs 18 - 20 V(as per the manufactures claim).

Comment: Have you tested the output of the "emulator" using a multimeter? What current does it claim to be able to output? I cannot find any such device outside of hobbyist sites saying it is a bad idea. Where did you get it from?

Comment: I have not tested it. I bought it from amazon. Here is the link to that https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07SKDV8W7/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Get something like https://www.amazon.in/dp/B01MT8MC3N to check what voltage and current is being taken. If it is anything other than ~20V between your charger and that device then the problem is between those two devices. If you have a barrel connector of that type then there is going to be nothing smart enough in your laptop to cause a problem except in the case that it is getting a voltage that is too high or too low to work.

Comment: I agree on getting the right charger.  Many laptop chargers will communicate with the laptop on how much current can be supplied safely, performing this by a serial data "handshake" as variations in the voltage it supplies.  If the laptop doesn't see this then it will refuse to draw power.  A laptop that is dead can't perform this handshake so it will fallback to a low power charge mode when off or asleep.  A generic power adapter likely will not implement this handshake.  That is an educated guess on why the unknown chunk of questionable hardware acts as it does.